# Using "Format Document" in a Razor view, makes @code merge with import line

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, razor

I have this Razor document...

```
@Imports myproject
@Code
End Code
```

If I press CMD + K + D to format the document, then VS messes up the view and does this...

```
@Imports myproject@Code
End Code
```

Which of course make my view fail.

Anybody have a solution?

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me. You check out [UserVoice](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio) yet? There's [another issue](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/4185227-fix-code-formatting-indenting-when-using-tabs-in-m) in C# regarding tabs vs. spaces (maybe some how related?)

Comment: Nope haven't checked that out yet. Well it was there in VS2012.